# Не могу разобраться как правильно использовать функцию localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть скрытый `div`, который разблокируется после выполнения скрипта, мне нужно чтобы он оставался разблокированным после перезагрузки страницы для пользователя, который прошел проверку. Если есть возможность то установить таймер, по истечению которого он снова будет блокироваться после перезагрузки страницы.

```
$(function() {
  $('#podt').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/inc/test_code_sms.php', $('#form1').serialize(), function(data) {
      alert(data)
      if (data == ("Номер активирован")) {
        let content = document.getElementById("content")
        content.style.display = "block"
        localStorage.setItem('content', 1);
      };
    });
  });
});

localStorage.getItem('content'); //1
```

Comment: что конкретно у вас не получается? Вон getItem делаете, получаете значение. Вы условие не можете написать или что?

Comment: в общем мой код это подтверждение номера телефона и если код из смс верен то раскрывается див с кнопкой, мне нужно чтобы у человека который прошел верификацию осталась кнопка открытой после перезагрузки страницы, сейчас этого не происходит и кнопка исчезает и я не могу понять что я делаю не так.